# Angular form with material Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

[How to solve this. I am new in angular. so, solve this gyz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDpBn.png)

Comment: `loginForm!: FormGroup;` you need to add `!(Exclamation mark)` in the Angular 12 when the class property doesn't have a default value or will not be initialized by the constructor it will throw an error. So you need to tell typescript it will be initialized in another way. By the way, when you are asking a question in Stackoverflow you need to provide more details, explain your issue, and share some code examples, this was an easy issue, but sometimes it will be hard to understand by looking at the image.

Comment: move ngOnInit code into constructor

Comment: Please share the actual code or a representation of it instead of sharing a picture.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the code work you need to use what is called a definite assignment assertion as described here (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions).
This tells TypeScript that although it can’t detect that the respective variable is assigned, it will be assigned.
Basically, if you change line 10:

```
loginForm: FormGroup
```

to:

```
loginForm!: FormGroup
```

your code should work.